# How to compare instance data of objects

Tags: java, instance

So I am having an issue where I am creating many Earthquake objects from the class Earthquake. I store five pieces of data from each earthquake into the instance data of the class. I then want to compare the instance data of one to the instance data of another.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: show us your code and what have you tried

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Use the comparable interface if your aim is to order them, or override the equals method to test for equality only.

Comment: Override the equals method in the Earthquake class, and then use the instance1.equals(instance2); to know if they are equals.

Answer (score 0):

To compare custom objects, you can define the compareto method in your object from the interface `comparable`.

The method body would be like this :

```
@Override
public int compareto(Earthquake eq)
{
    //compare your object attributes and define what should be returned
}
```

The method must return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

**Don't forget to implement java.lang.Comparable at the top of your Earthquake object**

```
public class Eartquake implements Comparable
{
    ...
}
```

Then you would call `currentEarthquake.compareto(otherEarthquake) < 0` to check if the current is less than the other.

`currentEarthquake.compareto(otherEarthquake) == 0` to check if equals
`currentEarthquake.compareto(otherEarthquake) > 0` to check greater

See Comparable documentation for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html